# C# Preprocessor for 32BitProcess running on 64BitOperatingSystem

Tags: c#

How do find 32BitProcess running on 64BitOperatingSystem using C# Preprocessor directivies.

For More info, i need to declare the dll name(based on the bit) to access the extern function. I need the following code using Preprocessor way.

```
public String WABDll; 
if (64Bit)
{
    WABDll = "Win-64.dll";
}
else if(32Bit Process on 64BitOS)
{
   WABDll = "Win-32on64.dll";
}
else if(32Bit)
{
    WABDll = "Win-32.dll";
}
```

i tried the following way

```
#if _64BIT
    public const String WABDll = "Win-64.dll";
#elif _32BIT
    public const String WABDll = "Win-32on64.dll";
#else
    public const String WABDll = "Win-32.dll";
#endif
```

Any Suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this with preprocessor directives; determine the environment at runtime using [the Environment class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8te35sa.aspx). The `Is64BitOperatingSystem` and `Is64BitProcess` properties should give you the information you need.

Comment: if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem) { if (System.Environment.Is64BitProcess) { } else { } } else { } i tried already this way. But i need it Preprocessor while loading the DLLImport.

Comment: @BrittoRaj - but at *compile* time, you don't *know* what machine your code is going to run on. Write two separate DLLImports and decide (as per this answer) which one to call at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve this:

```
else if(32Bit Process on 64BitOS)
{
   WABDll = "Win-32on64.dll";
}
```

compile time, since compiler does not know in advance where the program will run.
I can suggest you creating more solution "paltform", declaring some custom compiler flag and using them accordingly. Of course you need to know deploy time which executable must run on which platform.

Comment: I gave the scenario for example.

Comment: That does not change the fact that you cannot know that at compile time